# Two flavours with different resources inheriting layout from one base flavour

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have my android application split into four different build flavours. Each of these flavours have a portion of unique `java` and `xml` files, and a portion of shared files under `main`. For the sake of clarity, let's call these `Cucumber`, `Tomato`, `Onion` and `Pepper`. These flavours have unique layouts, drawables, strings, colours, java files, etc.

My requirement is now that I need to split my `Pepper` flavour into two sub-flavours; `Red-Pepper` and `Green-Pepper`. The layouts for these two flavours should be identical - the only different is that the two flavours must use different `drawable` and `string` resources. I don't want to have duplicate layout files in both the red and green flavours for obvious reasons.

How can this be achieved in `gradle`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can define multiple resource folders.
In this way you can use common folders for 2 flavors (in you redPepper and greenPepper).
For example something like this:

```
android {
     ...
     sourceSets {
            main {
                //....
                res.srcDirs = ['/src/main/res']

            }
            redPepper {
                 res.srcDirs = ['/src/flavorRed/res', '/src/commonPepper/res']
            }
            greenPepper {
                 res.srcDirs = ['/src/flavorGreen/res', '/src/commonPepper/res']
            }     
            //.....other flavors   
     }
}
```

Comment: if the layout files are common move them to commonPepper/res/layout, or main/res/layout.

Comment: I had worked it out by re-reading your answer, but thank you very much for the clarification. It's working now. (For the benefit of other readers, I also added `java.srcDirs = ['/src/commonPepper/java']` to the green and red flavours, as the shared code was the same). Thanks very much Gabriele.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but this solution didn't work for me until I removed the leading slash.
    'src/commonPepper/res'
worked